# How do I convert HTML to HAML in textmate?

Tags: rvm, haml, textmate, textmate2, html2haml

I'm trying to write a textmate 2 command to convert the selected text from HTML to HAML. I'm use RVM so I installed html2haml gem to a textmate specific gemset and set TM_RUBY variable to /Users/mark/.rvm/bin/ruby-1.9.3-p392@Textmate as per https://rvm.io/integration/textmate

here's my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ -f "${TM_SUPPORT_PATH}/lib/bash_init.sh" ]] && . "${TM_SUPPORT_PATH}/lib/bash_init.sh"

echo "$TM_SELECTED_TEXT" | html2haml -s
```

but this gives the error "command not found html2haml" because html2haml is installed in an rvm gemset and textmate is running a bash script so it doesn't know about TM_RUBY. How do I sort this mess out?

Comment: have you tried `$TM_RUBY -S html2haml -s`?

Comment: @mpapis That worked! Add it as an answer here so I can mark it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to use the `TM_RUBY` as ruby has `-S` which does `PATH` search:

```
echo "$TM_SELECTED_TEXT" | $TM_RUBY -S html2haml -s
```